# Реально ли получить значение URL браузера на PHP?

Tags: php

Всем доброго дня. Задача состоит следующая - хочется проверить url, и если человек использует анонимайзер (будет расхождение в хосте) сделать редирект.

На jQ решение не подходит, т.к его можно отключить через консоль и редиректа на будет.

Все условия смогу сделать сама, вопрос только в возможности получения значения URL именно на PHP

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что когда страница уже у пользователя, пхп код уже отработал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Comment: через анонимайзер все равно $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] выводит мой адрес

Comment: а что вы хотите получить?

Comment: @L.Vadim автор считает, что "если человек использует анонимайзер (будет расхождение в хосте)". Как-то так )

Comment: @L.Vadim, на jq именно так

Comment: Может в клиенте есть разшождения, но до сервера это не доходит.
на php будет всегда один хост.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вопрос глупый. Но если мы через jq получим url - добавим его в переменную php и сделаем условие - решение, или не стоит того?

Comment: вы можете это сделать, почему сразу через jq не обработать полученный url?